# Does the sentence "the president drives the country through the difficulty" make any sense?

Tags: meaning

Once upon a time, I heard an American president say *drive the country*.

I am not sure I misheard or not.

If *drive the country* is idiomatic expression, then what is the meaning of *drive* in this case?

*Drive* in this case seems to be similar to *lead*.

Comment: Please pay more careful attention to formatting. This is the second ransom note from you I’ve had to fix. It doesn’t look good to have all that ugly blue monospace, and all the extra quotes just distract. Use simple italics please.

Answer (score 0):

The captain steers the ship.  The driver drives the bus.  In both of these cases, the subject of the sentence is controlling things, and doing complex navigation to get the object to where it ought to go.  Same with the president driving the country.

You are right, this is a creative way of talking about leading.  But it's not terribly common.

Comment: I also believe it is a creative way to say but seem it is not a common idiom

Comment: If you want a common idiom with "drive", here's a useful one: "She's driving me crazy!"

Answer (score 0):

It is tortuous usage to say

> The president drives the country through difficulties

if what is meant is

> The president leads the country through difficulties

because the true intent of action in the statement is "to lead," which you would not say about the actions of a bus driver.

However, given that the sentence was uttered by an American president, perhaps he was alluding to *driving* cattle from one pasture to a greener one.

[image: Patton on drive vs. lead]

Comment: A common idiom for what the President does is "steer the ship of state". It's not as easy to turn quickly as a car is, but a ship is presumably less able than cattle to wander off in all directions.  And one does not "lead" a ship—a ship is steered from the rear.